# Laravel - Axios GET request fails but POST works

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I have something strange going on with my Laravel/Vue application and cant figure it out.  Within Laravels web.php, I have a simple route

```
Route::get('api/test', 'UploadController@test');
```

If I do `route:list` I can see the correct route

```
| GET|HEAD  | api/test | App\Http\Controllers\UploadController@test | web,auth  |
```

I have simplified the controller for now so it is like so

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function test() 
    {
        dd("IN");
    }
}
```

And the Axios request is simply

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                files: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            loadFiles() {
                axios.get("api/test").then(({ data }) => (this.files = data));
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.loadFiles();
            Fire.$on('AfterCreate',() => {
                this.loadFiles();
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is where things get strange.  Checking the console, I can see that the request URL is `http://localhost:8000/api/test` which is correct.  I am getting a 200 response, but it is not showing my output, just the whole HTML code for the page.

If I change the request to POST, then I see the output for this function.

Am I missing something here?  Why would POST work but GET not?

Thanks

**Update**
Managed to get it working, but not sure why.  I have another page that displays users, and the GET request for this was working fine.  I then wanted to check my api.php route file to make sure nothing in here was stopping the test.  I noticed I still had my user one in here, so I deleted it, and then my user stopped working.

So in api.php, I have added

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

And now both work.  Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: try to remove the `dd` and instead use `return response()->json(['abc']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `dd("IN")` in your `public function test()`, which will output HTML (and the CSS/JS) necessary to render the contents of your `dd()` function in a fancy, interactive element. API calls need to actually return something usable, such as a `json` response:

```
public function test(){
  return response()->json(["status" => "OK"], 200);
}
```

Edit: Also, be aware of conflicting routes. All the routes in `routes/api.php` are prefixed automatically with `/api`, so defining the following two routes will be a conflict:

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get("/api/test", ...);
```

routes/api.php:

```
Route::get("/test", ...);
```

I'm not 100% on which would be used in this situation, but it's likely the one in `routes/web.php`, as it is defined later in the code. Also, if you use `Route::get("/api/test", ...);` in `routes/api.php`, then your actual route would be `http://localhost/api/api/test` (notice the double prefix), so be aware of that too.

Comment: Thanks, made an edit with an update, very strange behaviour.

Comment: "*I have another page that displays users, and the GET request for this was working fine [...]"* This is 100% because those routes don't have a `dd()` in them, but a correct  `return` statement. `dd()` is short for "dump and die", which halts execution of PHP and renders the contents of that function as HTML, CSS and JS, which is why you're getting the "actual page". Not strange behaviour, just how API calls work in Laravel.

Comment: Yes, but it also works with a dd.  I have added a normal response, and it is the same.  The only solution is what I mentioned in the update above.  I think because I am using the api prefix, it is getting confused with RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: Ok yes, conflicting routes maybe? If you have `'/api/test` in `routes/web.php`, then it's going to conflict with `/test` in `routes/api.php`. I'll add that as an edit.